# Nested Xlookup First Non-blank Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Name    Day 1    Day2   Day 3
John    3       2
John    2   1   4
```

Using a double Xlookup, when I'm searching for John and Day 2, I cannot get the value 1 and I'm trying Index/Xmatch/xmatch to return me 1 but no luck. Any idea to go about it?

@@@Updated example picture here@@@
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zUOH.png)

This is my current formula

```
=XLOOKUP("John",$A$2:$A$3,XLOOKUP("Day 2",$B$1:$D$1,$B$2:$D$3),,2)
```

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I use 2 because in my original data it is searching for a full name, hence I'm not searching for the name "John" instead, I have this B3&"*". I don't really have a copiable data as I'm working on obtaining the shift time so I just replaced those values.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Instead of Day, it is date. And for Day 2, if John has 2 lines and his first line was purposely blanked out, I want to extract his shift time which is 1 but I'm obtaining "Saturday, January 0, 1900" as my answer instead of a string, in this case: "1"

Answer (score 0):

Note that your comments show a different case (wildcard search in names) than your question.

The following formula will result in the first found value of the wildcard search for names starting with the search string in `F2` and matching the date in `F3`:

```
=LET(range,A1:D3,
     c,1-COLUMNS(range),
     r,1-ROWS(range),
       days,TAKE(range,1,c),
       names,TAKE(range,r,1),
       data,TAKE(range,r,c),
            x,FILTER(data,days=F3),
TAKE(
     FILTER(x,
              (ISNUMBER(XMATCH(F2&"*",names,2)))*
              (x<>"")),
     1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for you input but if you add someone on top of John say Lily with values in each day, it doesn't return 1 but return's Lily's number

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [XLOOKUP two-way exact match](https://exceljet.net/formulas/xlookup-two-way-exact-match), because it returns the first match and you have duplicated values in column **Name**.

This solution returns the first non blank value from the input data based on the lookup values. In cell `H2` put the following formula:

```
=LET(colIdx, XMATCH(G3,A1:D1), tb, A2:D5, lkCol, INDEX(tb,, colIdx),
  INDEX(TAKE(FILTER(tb, (A2:A5=G2) * (lkCol<>0), "Not Found"),1),colidx)
)
```

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

We use `LET` for easier reading and composition. First we need to identify the column of our interest. The name `colIdx`, has the column index. Notice in order to deal with only one data range (`tb`), I search in all column names including **Name**. Now we need to identify the corresponding column values. The name `lkCol` represents that.

Now we have all the elements we need to filter and select the information we are looking for:

```
FILTER(tb, (A2:A5=G2) * (lkCol<>0), "Not Found")
```

The output will be the rows from `tb` for name `G2` and filtered for non empty rows from `G3` column name. The output has all the columns, now we need to select the column of our interest and only the *first* non empty value. `TAKE` extracts only the first row and `INDEX` the corresponding column.